# Any tip on solving the differential equation $y - y' \cdot \cos x = y^2 \cdot \cos x \cdot \left( 1 - \sin x \right)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the following differential equation to solve:

$$y - y'  \cdot \cos x = y^2  \cdot \cos x  \cdot \left( 1 - \sin x \right)$$

Can someone give me any small tip/guideline on solving it? Just knowing the method (let's say that it's a Bernouli equation, which I am not sure) would be helpful.

Thank you,

Comment: this is a Bernoulli equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed Bernoulli type equation. Divide by $y^2$ :

$$-\frac{1}{y^2}y' + \frac{1}{y} \sec(x) = 1-\sin x$$

Now let $1/y = w$ to get to the following linear equation:

$$w' + w \sec(x) = 1-\sin(x)$$

Edit:

As mentioned in comments, we get the above result when $y(x) \neq 0$. Other solution of differential equation is $y = 0$ which is seen from original equation.

Comment: and if $y(x)=0$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner - $y=0$ is a solution of the original equation, so that's not an issue.

Comment: You wrote $...-\sin x\to ...-\sin(w)$

Comment: @samjoe thank you, I've got $\displaystyle y = \frac{\sec x + \tan x}{\sin x + C}$ as a final answer. Does that match yours? Thank you.

Comment: @Holo Yeah mate corrected it.

Comment: @bru  seems all good to me